# Using cubic-bezier transition with Bootstrap Tabs button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make tab button switching animation like this reference where its not using Bootstrap Tabs.

```js
var tabs = $('.tabs');
var selector = $('.tabs').find('a').length;
//var selector = $(".tabs").find(".selector");
var activeItem = tabs.find('.active');
var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
$(".selector").css({
  "left": activeItem.position.left + "px",
  "width": activeWidth + "px"
});

$(".tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  var itemPos = $(this).position();
  $(".selector").css({
    "left": itemPos.left + "px",
    "width": activeWidth + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h6 {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #777;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.tabs a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tabs .selector {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  background: #05abe0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Elastic Tabs</h2>
  <h6>Click on tabs to see them in action</h6>
  <nav class="tabs">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Avengers</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>Hulk</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Thor</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-burn"></i>Marvel</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

This is the Bootstrap Tabs that I'm using , I tried to find reference that could achieve the above transitions but couldn't find any.

```css
.nav-link {
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 1, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-messages" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-settings" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">Profile</div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab" tabindex="0">Messages</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab" tabindex="0">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice or help that I could get in order to achieve the transition animation that I need with Bootstrap Tabs button ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that animated background element built-into bootstrap, the only transitions happening are changes in color.
You can override the transition property values by using a selector with higher specificity like: `#v-pills-tab .nav-link`. In the snippet below you will see the colors transition according to your timing function and duration.

```css
#v-pills-tab .nav-link {
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 1, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-messages" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-settings" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">Profile</div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab" tabindex="0">Messages</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab" tabindex="0">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 
javascript should be included after all content https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js
-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```